# Running a browser inside a neovim buffer

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I would like to open website inside a buffer so I don't have to switch windows when developing web applications. Are there plugins which integrate a firefox or chrome window in neovim?

I can only open a terminal in a buffer and open a terminal based browser such as w3m. But that's of course not very satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

> Are there plugins which integrate a firefox or chrome window in neovim?

No, there isn't and it's likely not happening in the near future since you'd need to implement a GUI-Like window inside neovim which is mainly  used as a terminal program.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this plugin called [vim-browser-search](https://github.com/voldikss/vim-browser-search.git)?
It says it has NeoVim compatibility, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [firenvim](https://github.com/glacambre/firenvim) project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).